# Which non-printable ASCII characters have no side-effects?

Tags: non-ascii-characters

I want to use a couple of non-printable ASCII characters to encode special meanings to text generated by an application (under Linux).

Some non-printable ASCII characters are interpreted to have special meanings in a sheer number of applications, such as LF (linefeed), character number 10 in the ASCII table. I am unsure if there are more of these. Basically, I am looking for a character, where the function of which is outdated and safe to use in the modern world.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The 1980s called and wanted its text encoding back. Seriously, the entire ASCII character table is available hundreds of places online and not that complicated. You could just look at yourself. But you are going to be disappointed. It's only 7 bits, so there's not much room for fluff. All of the characters tend to have a meaning. Which gets us back to: why are you using ASCII?

Comment: @CodyGray: I know what the table looks like, I use it very often. My question was, which of the first 31 characters are safe to use, text-editors usually don't assign any functionality to that particular character. For example, I have never seen the use of characters like DLE and DC1 (0x10, 0x11), but I am not sure, whether  they might mean something special to some program people use.